Tabulator will call the API twice when clearing headerfilter and setting sort
When I use the tabulator, I have a function that want to clear headerfilter and reset the sort, but when I do it, it will call API twice, I set the filtermode and sortmode as remote in the setting of Tabulator
const options= { layout: 'fitDataStretch', pagination: true, paginationMode: 'remote', paginationInitialPage: 1, ajaxURL: '/api/getdatas', filterMode: 'remote', sortMode: 'remote',
}
table.clearHeaderFilter();
table.setSort([{ column: 'number', dir: 'desc' }]);

Can we call the API only once when clear headerfilter and setsort?
